# React Native (android) , components overlapping with shadow issue

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, react-native

I am using a custom component with image and text. The image is relative to the text. Please see the screenshot.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pTAD.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlS0p.png).

I have used the TouchableOpacity component as root view for that.

In screenshots when long press on the component, two views are overlapping with shadow. It looks ugly when long press.

Please see the code below for reusable component.

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ExampleButton extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
  }
  _handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log('pressed!!!');
  };

  render () {
    console.log (this.props);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.handleOnPress}
      >
        <View style={styles.btnCompContainer}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FFF',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              borderRadius: 30,
              height: 50,
              width: '100%',
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>{this.props.buttonText}</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={[styles.btnElmContainer]}>
            <Image
              style={[{height: 30, width: 30,resizeMode:'stretch'}]}
              source={this.props.image}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  btnCompContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  btnElmContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    borderRadius: 30,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
    },
    elevation:5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
  },
  btnTxt: {
    marginLeft: 80,
    color: '#9e9e9e',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
});
```

Here I am using this reusable component in code.

```
    'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  StyleSheet, 
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View, 
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  Easing
} from 'react-native';

//  Custom Components

const searchBGImg = require('../assets/search-bg-kit.png');
const houseLogo = require('../Resources/house.png');

import ExampleButton from './components/common/example-button';


export default class TypeSelect extends Component<Props> {
  //  Navigation Option
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  constructor() {
    super();  
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
      x: new Animated.Value(-100),
    };
  }
  slide = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.state.x, {
      toValue: 0,
      easing: Easing.easeOutBack
    }).start();
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };
  gotoSearch = () =>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DocSearch')
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.slide();
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={searchBGImg} style={styles.imgBG}>
          <View style={{alignItems:'center', marginBottom:20}}> 
            <Image style={{height:57, width:69, marginBottom:12}} source={houseLogo} />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Animated.View
              style={[styles.slideView, {
                transform: [
                  {
                    translateX: this.state.x
                  }
                ]
              }]}>

              <ExampleButton image={houseLogo} buttonText={'Click here'} />
              <ExampleButton image={houseLogo} buttonText={'Click here'} />

            </Animated.View>  
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  imgBG:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent:"center",
    width: "100%", 
    height: "100%"
  }
})
```

It is working fine in iOS, but it's not working in android up to the mark. Please help me to work it in android. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `renderToHardwareTextureAndroid` prop on `<View />` component.

In your example like this:

```
   <View style={styles.btnCompContainer} renderToHardwareTextureAndroid >
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRadius: 30,
          height: 50,
          width: '100%',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>{this.props.buttonText}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={[styles.btnElmContainer]}>
        <Image
          style={[{height: 30, width: 30,resizeMode:'stretch'}]}
          source={this.props.image}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```